# How many HF (FT8/JT65/BPSK/RTTY etc) amateurs are active in Canada?

Tags: canada, ft8

It's silent over there... USA is full of FT8 stations, in Canada you can count them on one hand and you don't even need all your fingers...

Comment: Respectfully, can you provide us with a reference showing that?

Comment: The title says "How many" and the body of your question says "Why?" Please [edit] your question to clarify it, and note that "why" is likely to be essentially only answerable by speculation, which is not allowed.

Comment: This would be a good use case for downloading and analyzing wsprnet / pskreporter data

Comment: IMO this question is not at all unclear, and eliminating the "why" part is a simple edit. Doesn't deserve to be closed.

Comment: By the way, my question is very clear. You just need to read it.

Comment: Glad I got my answer in time. According to God AG6YO I have no right because I can see the question is still locked because HE doesn't understand...

Comment: @PatrickVerschuren Well, Kevin AG6YO is not quite the man you think. :-) This site is a little different from other sites, and he was just going by the [site guidelines](https://ham.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions). We look forward to helping you with your next question, my friend. You may find our [code of conduct](https://ham.stackexchange.com/conduct) and [help](https://ham.stackexchange.com/help) helpful.

Answer (score 2):

If there is any merit to your claim, consider that Canada has ~ 69,000 hams while the US has ~800,000 hams [according to Wikipedia](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Amateur_radio_operator). With less than 10% of the number of hams in Canada compared to the US, it is plausible that for any mode you will hear far less Canadian hams than US hams.

If you then project that the population density of hams follows the general [population density](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Canadian_provinces_and_territories_by_population), Canada will have the majority of the ham population in the Quebec and Ontario provinces and then generally closer to the US border. If you are located within this region you are less likely to "hear" the majority of Canadian hams on HF frequencies due to propagation effects.

Comment: This is what I couldn't find. "consider that Canada has ~ 69,000 hams while the US has ~800,000 hams according to Wikipedia."

I have my info from PSK-reporter and my own experience. I don't work Canada on a weekly base. USA a couple of time a day...

That's why I came to this question.

Thanks for the answer :)

73, Patrick
PE5I